# Sharepoint : What is the WebFullUrl property in a list item?

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know what the WebFullUrl property is in a sharepoint list? Can't find any documentation on the subject, thanks

Comment: Which version of SharePoint is this? My SharePoint 2007 does not appear to have a "WebFullUrl" property in neither an SPList nor an SPListItem.

Comment: @CCornet - MOSS2007, I get this property from a CAML web service call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Lists Web Service Protocol Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/8/858F2155-D48D-4C68-9205-29460FD7698F/%5BMS-LISTSWS%5D.PDF), the WebFullUrl property is "The server-relative path to the subsite that contains the list". So it would be the server-relative path to the SPWeb object that holds the list in question (the site). You can find an except of the property list for the lists web service at the following link: [ListDefinitionCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd774270.aspx).